# Understanding an IC, MP1584, error amplifier

Tags: integrated-circuit

[image]

Here is the IC's circuit diagram. After reading through the datasheet, I still don't get what this COMP pin does and how to use it. Can someone explain to me the function and purpose of this pin in pure English?

Answer (score 2):

It is a loop compensation node, it adjusts the feedback loop gain to keep the system fast and stable.

Determining appropriate component values requires quite some elaboration. You need to use an *averaged model* of current mode buck controller to make bode plots of control-to-output and output-to-feedback. Then you insert poles and zeros to get the required phase margin. Since it is a current-mode controller, one pole should be enough.

If you want to dig deeper into this subject, take a look at Christophe Basso's books.

Answer (score 2):

How deep down the rabbit hole do you want to go?

From the question I assume you don't know a great deal about control theory, otherwise the answer should have popped out at you. I'm not going to go into detail or background here, for the following reason:

*The [datasheet](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/4/4e/MP1584_r1.0.pdf) contains a table on page 13 showing the necessary component values for a selection of voltages, which should be sufficient. If not, the datasheet provides calculations to select your own values. Failing that, you need to consider learning control theory or selecting a different IC.*

In simple terms, the COMP pin is the output of the comparator that checks what the voltage at FB is compared to what it should be - if it's too low it turns the output MOSFET on. If it's too high, it switches it off. Incessant switching of the comparator is undesireable - too fast a reaction and the MOSFET will be switching on and off slower than it's being told to, which will lead to instability. It's necessary to 'slow down' the response by adding a *compensation network* - `R3` and `C3` in the datasheet. Not too slow though, or the output will react poorly to transients. A crossover frequency of one-tenth of the output switching frequency is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it clears up a bit, but still cloudy. I saw some tiny board module made with this IC, and want to learn to make one myself from scratch. The question is, what if the output voltage is adjustable? then what should I do with this compensation network?

Comment: You use a different IC. Changing `Vout` requires fundamental changes, namely the output inductor and `C2`. These ICs are designed for high regulation and high accuracy, and the ability to determine whether transient loads (large changes in the current drawn by the load) are answered immediately or somewhat ignored, *but only ever for one voltage*. If you want to adjust the voltage, use something that's designed to offer a freely adjustable voltage.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1x-Tiny-4-5-28V-3A-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Step-down-Power-Regulator-MP1584EN-/141524007951

This buck converter use this IC. and the output voltage is adjustable from 0.8V to 20V. so this module is not a good one to buy?